# Why can't Tensorflow find the GPU kernel of my custom Op?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cuda

I have followed the [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#gpu_kernels) example on the Tensorflow website for adding a GPU kernel to my custom Op. It compiles fine, but when I try to use the GPU kernel, Tensorflow gives me this error:

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'b': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.`

<s>Can anyone point me to where I went wrong?</s> I'm using the exact example code given on the page linked above, with the following fixes/changes (found on various other forums and StackOverflow pages):

- Added `#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"` to `kernel_example.cu.cc`
- Changed `"example.h"` to `"kernel_example.h"` in `kernel_example.cu.cc` and `kernel_example.cc`
- Added `//` to the line `#endif // KERNEL_EXAMPLE_H_` in `kernel_example.h`
- Corrected the partial specialization in `kernel_example.h` to:

  `template <typename T> struct ExampleFunctor<Eigen::GpuDevice, T> { ... };`
- Registered the op in `kernel_example.cc`:

  `REGISTER_OP("Example").Attr("T: {float, int32} = DT_FLOAT").Input("input: T").Output("output: T"));`
- Corrected the last lines of the `.cu.cc` file to `template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, float>;` (the `struct` was missing)

Makefile:

```
TF_LIB := $(shell python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())' 2>/dev/null)
TF_INC := $(shell python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())' 2>/dev/null)

CUDA_LIB=/z/sw/packages/cuda/8.0/lib64

all: kernel_example.cu.cc kernel_example.cc
    nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o kernel_example.cu.o kernel_example.cu.cc -I $(TF_INC) -I$(TF_INC)/external/nsync/public -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED --expt-relaxed-constexpr

    g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o kernel_example.so kernel_example.cc kernel_example.cu.o -I $(TF_INC) -I$(TF_INC)/external/nsync/public -fPIC -L$(CUDA_LIB) -lcudart -L$(TF_LIB) -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1
```

**EDIT: As noted in my answer below, the issue arose from `g++` call lacking `-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1`.**

Testing code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
example_lib = tf.load_op_library('kernel_example.so')

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='a')
    b = example_lib.example(a, name='b')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(b))
```

Comment: You are not compiling the cuda code for your GPUs architecture, in all likelihood

Comment: @talonmies Can you elaborate? My Makefile is given in the question; is there some other way I should be compiling the code?

Comment: *if* that is really an underlying CUDA API error being reported by Tensorflow, then you might need to add an `arch=...` to match whatever your GPU is to the nvcc state. But I am not 100% certain that what Tensorflow is reporting is actually a CUDA error

Comment: OK so that wasn't a CUDA runtime error, even though it is worded almost exactly like one

Comment: Nope, but your comment did lead me to Google the right things to figure out errors I found down the road. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow documentation is just bad and incomplete like normal. The `g++` command was missing `-D GOOGLE_CUDA=1`. I'll edit the question to reflect this.